# Loopback.js - Extending the base "User" model into "user" without MongoDB creating "User" and "user" collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs

Loopback is pretty cool, but this is the one drawback that I've encountered so far, and I'm really not sure of how to address it. The built-in user model produces a collection named "User" in my MongoDB database, and, when I attempt to extend the User model as per Loopback.js' own recomendation, I end up with two collections: "User" and "user." Not good. The former contains authentication-related stuff, and the latter ends up containing the actual relevant user attributes like "firstName" and "lastName," and the collections themselves are otherwise disconnected. Is there a way to just have all of that data go into a single collection?

Comment: Did you adjust your `model-config.json` to contain only your extended `user` model?

Answer (score 0):

The loopback docs are a bit confusing there. I had exactly the same questions a couple weeks ago! What you need to do is the following:

1. Extend the User model and call it 'Account' or something. A loopback guideline is to NOT call your extended model 'user'.
2. Go to server/model-config.json and find the base model "User". Set public to false.
3. Done :) 
   Now fire up the explorer! The /api/User endpoint is now gone and you will see that all the base properties for the 'User' object are now also in your extended model!

Comment: It's still completely fine to call it `user` if that's the requirement for API. You need to be disciplined and understand which of `user`/`User` are you using in which situation, but you can definitely do that.